# html form is not responsive even after adding the meta tag

Tags: html, css

My html form [arpitpkh.pythonanywhere.com](http://arpitpkh.pythonanywhere.com) works fine on pc but not responsive on mobile phones(I'am using iphone7) even though i've added the `<meta>` tag.

Here's my html code for 'home.html'

What's wrong with my code?? What should i change in my code?

```css
body {
  background-image: url("/static/grey.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 250px;
  font-size: 70px;
  color: coral;
}

.input2:hover {
  background-color: coral;
  color: white;
}

.input1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 37%;
  width: 250px;
  height: 30px;
}

.input2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 59.4%;
  left: 59%;
  width: 87px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Weather Forecast</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/static/main.css" />
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    <form action='/weather' method="post">
      <h1>City Name:</h1><input class="input1" type="text" name="city_name"> <br/>
      <input class="input2" type="submit" name="form" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: "Responsive" is a really, *really* **broad** term meaning "Adapts to screen size". `<meta viewport>` is **not** a magic wand that makes your design responsive, it just tells the browser that you think you have made your design responsive. You're essentially describing your problem as [doesn't work](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) which tells us very little. How do you *expect* your design to respond to changes in viewport size? What have you done to make that happen?

Comment: I am concerned with adapts to different screen sizes.

Comment: Then don't use things like `margin-top: 250px`. The h1 isn't even visible on small screens in landscape mode.

Comment: Please have a look that [this basic tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp) on responsive design fundamentals by w3schools. There are also great frameworks which will make it easier for you to design responsive websites, like [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/)

Answer (score -1):

You're using absolute positioning and defining sizes in px which stays the same on all screen sizes, making your design unresponsive.

You need to use responsive units like ems and media queries.
Check out this [article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/) on responsive design principles and this quick [tutorial](https://internetingishard.com/html-and-css/responsive-design/).